# Laravel 5.1 validation

Tags: validation, laravel

when I use validation in my controller or in a separate request file to validate request of form , it just **redirect** to itself. But when i remove the validation form just normally update the information please help me.

Here is the route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{university}'], function() {
Route::Resource('instructor', 'university\univInstructorController');
});
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\university;

use App\Http\Requests\university\instructor\instructorUpProfileReq;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\instructor;
use App\university;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class univInstructorController extends Controller
{
    public function update($university,$id, Request $request)
    {
        if($universities=university::whereuniversityName($university)->first()){
            if($instructors = instructor::find($id)){
                $this->validate($request, [
                    'name' => 'required|alpha|min:3',
                    'lName' => 'required|alpha|min:3',
                    'gender' => 'required|alpha',
                    'birth_date' => 'date',
                    'degree_type' => 'required|alpha',
                    'academic_degree' => 'required|alpha',
                    'phone' => 'max:15',
                    'address' => 'alpha_dash|min:4',
                ]);
                $input = $request->all();
                $instructors->update($input);
                return Redirect::action('university\univInstructorController@show',['universities'=>$university,'id'=>$id]);

            }
            else{
                return view('errors.404');
            }
        }
        else{
            return view('errors.404');
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is redirecting because the validation is failing, that is its default behavior for non ajax requests. If validation passes the execution continues.

Comment: what shows you what  message ?